# TensorFlow estimator DNNClassifier fails to do 2-time linear separation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, linear-regression

I'm trying to test out TensorFlow tf.estimator.**DNNClassifier** with some simple data

```
X = [[1,2], [1,12], [1,17], [9,33], [48,49], [48,50]]
Y = [ 1,     1,      1,      1,      2,       3     ]
```

The classifier takes 2 inputs: **x1,x2**; and is having this shape:

```
#these 4 layers supposed to be able to do even 4-time linear separation
hidden_units = [2000,1000,500,100]
n_classes    = 4
```

Hower, things didn't go as wanted, the network couldn't fit. Accuracy quickly got to **8.33** (=5/6) but stuck then. Loss converged to a horizontal line but not the zero line.

The data provided above are 2-time linear separable (right-click image to open in new tab):

[image]

Even when the network runs to 10,000 steps, it's still stuck, I guess it's stuck because it fails to separate the 2 values: Y=2 and Y=3, is it so? And how to make the network fit with the mentioned data.

Comment: First thing to do is to pre-process the input data. It's important how to map the integer values into neuron activation signals which are going from 0 to 1. Second step is to reduce the number of neurons to a much smaller amount. Using 2000 neurons on the first layer for calculating a simple mapping is massive over engineering.

Comment: i already tried both, normalising inputs and reducing neurons, but no good results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use these and it works:

- Use leaky relu or sigmoid
- Reduce number of layers
- Reduce number of neurons in each layer
- Normalise inputs
- Increase number of steps, epochs if needed